# Access history object using BrowserRouter

Tags: react-router

i need to access history to check whether user was on any website before. I thought i can accomplish this by using the history object and checking the "length" but i don't know how to access history while i also use `<BrowserRouter>` instead of `<Router>`

I'm using

```
   "react-router": "^6.3.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

Comment: you can try with usehistory hook of react-router-dom

Comment: I can't because of:

`Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'useHistory'`

Comment: `react-router-dom@6` doesn't directly any history object. Can you share a [mcve] for what you are using or trying to use?